# Single li item - specific background via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, indexing, html-lists, css-selectors

How would I target the very left li item and color it a different color?

I am currently selecting all horizontal items across this pretend setup when any item is hovered on:

```
<ul class="features">
<li class="category"><a href="services_hwrep.html">Hardware Repair</a></li>
<li class="category"><a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a></li>
<li class="category"><a href="services_printsetup.html">Printer Setup</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="features">
<li><a href="services_hwrep.html">Hardware Repair</a></li>
<li><a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a></li>
<li><a href="services_printsetup.html">Printer Setup</a></li>
</ul>


<ul class="features">
<li><a href="services_hwrep.html">Hardware Repair</a></li>
<li><a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a></li>
<li><a href="services_printsetup.html">Printer Setup</a></li>
</ul>
```

With this code:

```
$('ul.features li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $('ul.features > li:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ' )').toggleClass('pri_active');
});
```

So, if I were to hover on nth-child(2) of the third list, how could I change the background of nth-child(2) on the first list? (Has a class of 'category')

Any help is appreciated!

A live visual representation of what I'm trying to do can be found here:

http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/price.html

I want the highlighted left category li to be blue like the price li on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the class (`li.category:nth-child...`):

```
$('ul.features li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $('ul.features > li.category:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ' )').toggleClass('pri_active');
});
```

I got it working here: http://jsbin.com/ecunih/1/

Comment: So, in theory it works great :-P I have some internal styles that are breaking it, but I will upload it when I've completed it. I figured it'd be super easy... I just kept trying to tree back from (this) instead of just define it in the first place :-P

Thanks!

Comment: WORKING:
http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/price.html

Thanks! You da man :-P Did some weirdo tricky styling, but it looks clean now (minus minor bugs)